# nohup command in submitting jobs to cluster

Tags: unix, cluster-computing, nohup, qsub

I am trying to submit a job to a cluster that may take up to a few days. Usually, for a shorter job, I simply do qsub Arun1_scr and then wait for the job to finish while monitoring its status with qstat. the Arun_scr is a basic script. If I want to be able to exit the shell and maybe even turn off the computer while the job is being done on the cluster all I have to do is nohup qsub Arun1_scr?

Thank you!

Comment: So you're saying this is a script you run from within an interactive job?

Answer (score 4):

If you submit your job using **qsub Arun1_scr** you can exit the shell and it will still continue to run on the cluster. So, you do not need to change anything.

If you use **nohup** command and you want to run it into background the syntax is **nohup command-name &** ( without **&** your job will not be run in background and will be stopped after you close the shell).